# How to get value from an array based on the user selection?

Tags: ember.js, ember-paper

I've follow the ember-paper guide and defined the options data as below. The user is able to select any country from the options.

```
  timeZoneOptions: Object.freeze([
    { groupName: "Asia", options:["Kabul","Yerevan","Baku","Dhaka","Brunei","Bangkok","Shanghai","Urumqi","Taipei","Macau","Tbilisi","Dili","Kolkata","Jakarta"]},
    { groupName: "Australia", options: ["Darwin", "Eucla", "Perth", "Brisbane","Lindeman","Adelaide","Hobbart","Currie","Melbourne"]},
  ])
```

Here is the code for the select option. It will display the options groupby the `groupName`.

```
{{#paper-select options=this.timeZoneOptions
        selected=this.timeZone
        onChange=(action (mut this.timeZone)) as |timeZon| }}
        {{timeZon}}
      {{/paper-select}}
```

I can't get the data using `{{this.timeZone.groupName}}`.

How can I do if i want to get the `groupName` based on the option user selected?

Answer (score 1):

What you have there seems correct. Maybe the error lies in the `mut` usage, maybe it's somewhere else.

The `mut` helper is quite vague. It is gonna be deprecated when the Ember team figures out how to do it gracefully.

You can avoid the `mut` helper by creating a distinct action on your controller/component.

This will let you debug: simply put a `debugger` statement into your action and proceed from there.

### Classic Ember style:

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  timeZoneOptions: Object.freeze([
    { groupName: "Asia", options:["Kabul","Yerevan","Baku","Dhaka","Brunei","Bangkok","Shanghai","Urumqi","Taipei","Macau","Tbilisi","Dili","Kolkata","Jakarta"]},
    { groupName: "Australia", options: ["Darwin", "Eucla", "Perth", "Brisbane","Lindeman","Adelaide","Hobbart","Currie","Melbourne"]},
  ]),

  currentTimeZoneOption: null,

  actions: {
    selectTimeZoneOption(timeZoneOption) {
      this.set('currentTimeZoneOption', timeZoneOption');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
{{#paper-select
  options=this.timeZoneOptions
  selected=this.currentTimeZoneOption
  onChange=(action 'selectTimeZoneOption')
  as |timeZoneOption|
}}
  {{timeZoneOption}}
{{/paper-select}}

<p>
  Current timezone option:
  {{this.currentTimeZoneOption.groupName}}
</p>
```

### Ember Octane style:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  timeZoneOptions = Object.freeze([
    { groupName: "Asia", options:["Kabul","Yerevan","Baku","Dhaka","Brunei","Bangkok","Shanghai","Urumqi","Taipei","Macau","Tbilisi","Dili","Kolkata","Jakarta"]},
    { groupName: "Australia", options: ["Darwin", "Eucla", "Perth", "Brisbane","Lindeman","Adelaide","Hobbart","Currie","Melbourne"]},
  ]);

  @tracked
  currentTimeZoneOption = null;

  @action
  selectTimeZoneOption(timeZoneOption) {
    this.currentTimeZoneOption = timeZoneOption;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-component">
  <PaperSelect
    @options={{this.timeZoneOptions}}
    @selected={{this.currentTimeZoneOption}}
    @onChange={{this.selectTimeZoneOption}}
    as |timeZoneOption|
  >
    {{timeZoneOption}}
  </PaperSelect>

  <p>
    Current timezone option:
    {{this.currentTimeZoneOption.groupName}}
  </p>
</div>
```